# remove postgres server from local machine

Tags: postgresql, postgis, pgadmin

I know this is a real beginner question. But nevertheless I'm really confused:/
I wanted to have a clean installation of postgres on my ubuntu laptop. So I tried to [delete everything related to postgres](https://kb.objectrocket.com/postgresql/how-to-completely-uninstall-postgresql-757#:%7E:text=Navigate%20to%20the%20assigned%20directory,of%20your%20databases%20and%20tables).

However, when I start running the PgAdmin, I see this under the servers:

[image]

I don't even remember when I created this robin_test-server. But now I fail to remove, connect or find any information about it. Anybody might have an idea on what to do in this situation? Any help is super appreciated:)

Answer (score 1):

PgAdmin stores preferences and a list of servers in the `.pgadmin` directory in your HOME directory.

To reset it to a pristine state, you may delete this directory, when the application is not running.